# Typescript get the type of key inside generic

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have a class named Store that gets the state type as generic.

```
class Store<T> {

}
```

When I need to extend the store I am doing something like that:

```
interface State {
   entities: { [id: string] : Todo }
}

class Todos extends Store<State> {

}
```

But now I want to add a method in my store that returns the entities.

```
class Store<T> {

  private _store: BehaviorSubject<T>;

  constructor(initialState) {
    super();
    this._store = new BehaviorSubject(initialState);
  }

  getEntities() {
     return this._store.map(state => state.entities);
  }      
}
```

How can I define the return type of the `getEntities` to the Todo type in this case?

Comment: It's rxjs thing, not relevant.

Comment: `getEntities(): Observable<T>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can define getEntities generic return type the same way you define a generic type in your class declaration:

```
getEntities() : BehaviorSubject<T> {
   return this._store.map(state => state.entities);
}
```

Comment: T is the whole state type, I need the type of the entities key.